# How do I hibernate with s2disk from the menu?

Tags: 10.10, gnome, hibernate

I can hibernate my system with command "sudo s2disk". Now I'd like to call this from gnome menu with clicking on "Hibernate".

what I need to do?

Answer (score 0):

In `/etc/pm/config.d/00_sleep-module`, set the option to use uswsusp:

```
SLEEP_MODULE="uswsusp"
```

Comment: Add the OS version please. It seems you are at 11.10 and this question is tagged for 10.10

Comment: No, I _am_ on 15.10 – no way for me to (in)validate my answer now.

Comment: And this question is tagged for 10.10

Comment: So what? I will not add a tag if cannot check its validity. And I cannot check that ancient answer anymore.

Comment: http://askubuntu.com/questions/42010/hibernate-with-uswsusp-not-working-from-system-menu - You did the update to 11.10 an found problems so this answer is old but take note for future cases not to leave things loose. Did you file a bug on that version ?