# Hibernate with uswsusp not working from system menu

Tags: 11.04, hibernate

I can hibernate with `s2disk`, so this seems to be set up correctly. In `/etc/pm/config.d/00_sleep-module`, I have the line `SLEEP_MODULE="uswsusp"`, which *should* make the system use uswsusp for hibernation.

However, if I choose ‘Ruhezustand’ from the system menu (that’s hibernation in a German locale), it just does not work. I even see the warning about the missing splash system (which I always ignored). When called by hand, this is followed by the textual progress meter, but when called from the menu, that’s where it stucks. I cannot even imagine how to debug that.

It used to work before I upgraded to 11.04, so it is connected to the update somehow.

Addendum:

- running `pm-hibernate` as `root` works
- running `sudo s2disk` works
- however, `sudo pm-hibernate` fails

Now this is weird. Something in *my* environment makes `pm-hibernate` fail?

Comment: What about `pm-hibernate`?

Comment: I didn’t know aboud `pm-hibernate`, but it allowed me a few more tests. Thanks @psusi for pointing me at it.

Comment: `pm-hibernate` works most of the time.

Comment: Any update? I have same issue. Can not get working hibernate from shudown menu.